# Change default version of python in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, version

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 and I really don't know how does everything work yet. I use the last version of python in my windows system (3.8.1) and would like to use that version as well in ubuntu, but the "pre-installed" version of python is 2.7. Is there a way to uninstall that old version of python instead of changin the alias of the python command to match the version I want to use? Can you do that or does ubuntu need to have that version? If you could help me or explain this to me I would appreciate it.

Comment: Ubuntu uses that version. Keep it and also install 3.8 alongside it.

Comment: Also, there are some libraries that only work with earlier versions of Python, like Tensorflow and Keras.

Comment: You should use virtual environments, don't mess with the system's Python.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to remove Python 2 from your Ubuntu 18.04 because maybe some services or apps are using it (Despite that Python 2 doesn't get support any more)
(In Ubuntu 19.10, we have only Python 3)

The best answer is using [Virtual Environments](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-python-virtual-environments-on-ubuntu-18-04/) that make an isolate work station for you with any thing you wish, and it doesn't mess with other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Some services and application in Ubuntu use Python 2.x to run. It is not advisable to remove it. Rather, virtual environments maybe a good practice. There, you can work on Python 3.x, as per your needs, without messing up with the system's dependencies.